# How do I access a bean outside of a controller in ColdFusion Model Glue 3?

Tags: coldfusion, javabeans, coldfusion-9, model-glue, coldspring

Model Glue 3 introduced bean injection, which allows you to do this in a controller to access it:

```
beans.component.function();
```

However, the `beans` scope is only available for a controller. How would I access a bean outside of a controller, for example in `Application.cfc` or a helper UDF? I have a `SimpleConfig` bean that I'd like to access some config info for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to depend on your bean factory -- most likely ColdSpring. If your ColdSpring instance is saved in Application.beanFactory (I think this is the default, it's been some time since I last used ModelGlue), then you would do the following:

```
variables.config = application.beanFactory.getBean("SimpleConfig");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the bean factory does not exist on `application`.

Comment: Somewhere in Application scope, you'll find the Model Glue instance saved -- it might be Application._modelglue or something like that. If you can find that, then according to the docs (http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki/ReferenceMaterials/ModelGlueApi#Model-GlueAPI) you can call `{modelGlueObject}.GetBean("config");` (where "config" is the bean id of your config bean)